# Кодировка полетела в codeigniter 3

Tags: php, кодировка, mysqli, phpmyadmin, codeigniter

Проблемы с кодировкой.Использую codeigniter 3. Все было нормально. До этого проблем не возникало. Но сегодня ЧП. В базу нормально сохраняются. и Из бд все норм берется. но когда эти же данные хочу изменить и отправить в процесс файл, при просмотре с print_r все полетело, различные знаки итд. Не могу найти решение. С чем это связано?

Comment: проверьте кодировку файла

Comment: побольше бы инфы с примерами.

Comment: @madfan41k Кодировка ut8 без BOM стоит

Comment: @Улан, если apache можно в htaccess добавить AddDefaultCharset utf-8, если nginx то директива charset utf8;

Comment: @SergeyArchipov не помогает

Comment: @Улан, application/config/database.php

Comment: @Улан Как вариант, открыть файл в notepad++, вырезать с него всё, Кодировки -> Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM. Применить изменения. Сохранить фал как попросит. Сохранить. Вставить всё из буфера обмена обратно в файл и сохранить. Везде такое у меня прокатывает.